# Perl regular expression for searching a value inside a range

Tags: regex, perl, range

I want to search a value which comes inside a range x and y. I want a generic PERL regular expression because the x and y are dynamic.

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an excessively bad idea. Not impossible, but hard to write as a general solution.

Let's write a regular expression that matches all numbers between `2` and `123`. We have to look at each possible number of digits separately.

- 1 digit: `[2-9]` – 2 or larger
- 2 digits: `[1-9][0-9]` – any two-digit number
- 3 digits: `[1](?:[0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3])` – either any 3-digit number up to `119`, or `12x` where `0 <= x <= 3`.

Together: `/\A(?:[2-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1](?:[0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3]))\z/`

Is this readable or maintainable? Certainly not.

You could use embedded code: `/\A([0-9]+)(?(?{ not($x <= $^N && $^N <= $y) })(*F))\z/`, but that's rather silly as well.

The best solution is to use code for what should be done with code. Regexes are simply not an appropriate tool here.

```
my ($num) = $string =~ /\A([0-9]+)\z/ or die "no number in \$string";
if (not($x <= $num and $num <= $y)) {
   die "Number $num out of range [$x .. $y]";
}
```

Comment: `unless($x <= $num && $num <= $y){ ... }`

Comment: @Qtax I know – but I don't use `unless` any more as a style decision.

Comment: but you use `and` in `if`s? ;)